# Comparing two arrays and combining them Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, compare

I have two arrays

```
arr1 = [[["name", "Alex"],["age", "4"], ["width", "55"], ["weight", "30"], ["species", "Alex"], ["female", "yes"], ["group"]], [["name", "All"],["age", "7"], ["width", "26"], ["weight", "3"], ["species", "cat"], ["female", "no"], ["group"]]]

arr2 = [["A23", "All", "Katy", "Max"], ["B23", "Sisi", "Alex"]]
```

and if name eg. value Alex form the arr2 is like value Alex from the arr1, the value B23 from arr2 is pushed to subarray ["group"] to the first array. So I want to get

```
arr1 = [[["name", "Alex"],["age", "4"], ["width", "55"], ["weight", "30"], ["species", "Alex"], ["female", "yes"], ["group", "B23"]], [["name", "All"],["age", "7"], ["width", "26"], ["weight", "3"], ["species", "cat"], ["female", "no"], ["group", "A23"]]]
```

How to compare and combine those arrays?

Comment: Do you really have to use this data structure? This would be much better represented by a hash object.

Comment: Unfortunately yes...

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide any code, so I won't write a complete solution. As @EddeAlmeida commented, it would be much easier to work with an array of hashes. Here's a basic structure to convert your data forth and back :

```
require 'pp'

arr1 = [[["name", "Alex"],["age", "4"], ["width", "55"], ["weight", "30"], ["species", "Alex"], ["female", "yes"], ["group"]], [["name", "All"],["age", "7"], ["width", "26"], ["weight", "3"], ["species", "cat"], ["female", "no"], ["group"]]]

arr2 = [["A23", "All", "Katy", "Max"], ["B23", "Sisi", "Alex"]]

data = arr1.map { |a| a.tap { |x| x.last[1] = '' }.to_h }

pp data
# [{"name"=>"Alex",
#   "age"=>"4",
#   "width"=>"55",
#   "weight"=>"30",
#   "species"=>"Alex",
#   "female"=>"yes",
#   "group"=>""},
#  {"name"=>"All",
#   "age"=>"7",
#   "width"=>"26",
#   "weight"=>"3",
#   "species"=>"cat",
#   "female"=>"no",
#   "group"=>""}]

arr2.each do |code, *names|
  # add some logic here
end

# Coming back to (weird) nested arrays :
p data.map{|h| h.to_a}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done it like that:

```
arr1.each do |data|
    a = data[0][1]
    b = ""
    arr2.each do |x|
        if (x.include?(a)) then
            b << "#{x[0]} "
        end
    end
data[6].push(b)
```

end

Answer (score 0):

```
arr1 = [
        [["name", "Alex"],["age", "4"], ["width", "55"], ["weight", "30"],
         ["species", "Alex"], ["female", "yes"], ["group"]],
        [["name", "All"],["age", "7"], ["width", "26"], ["weight", "3"],
         ["species", "cat"], ["female", "no"], ["group"]]
       ]

arr2 = [["A23", "All", "Katy", "Max"], ["B23", "Sisi", "Alex"]]
```

Here is a way that allows the elements of each element of `arr1` to be in any order, and maintains that order after the element containing `"group"` is modified.

```
h2 = arr2.each_with_object({}) { |(first,*rest),h| rest.each { |s| h[s] = first } }
  #=> {"All"=>"A23", "Katy"=>"A23", "Max"=>"A23", "Sisi"=>"B23", "Alex"=>"B23"}

arr1.map do |a|
  h = a.each_with_object({}) { |(k,v),h| h[k]=v }
  h["group"] = h2[h["name"]]
  h.to_a
end
  #=> [[["name", "Alex"], ["age", "4"], ["width", "55"], ["weight", "30"],
  #     ["species", "Alex"], ["female", "yes"], ["group", "B23"]],
  #    [["name", "All"], ["age", "7"], ["width", "26"], ["weight", "3"],
  #     ["species", "cat"], ["female", "no"], ["group", "A23"]]]
```

Use `Array#map` if `arr1` is not to be mutated.

The block calculation for the first of the two elements of `arr1` is as follows.

```
a = arr1.first
  #=> [["name", "Alex"], ["age", "4"], ["width", "55"], ["weight", "30"],
  #    ["species", "Alex"], ["female", "yes"], ["group"]]
h = a.each_with_object({}) { |(k,v),h| h[k]=v }
  #=> {"name"=>"Alex", "age"=>"4", "width"=>"55", "weight"=>"30",
  #    "species"=>"Alex", "female"=>"yes", "group"=>nil}
v = h["name"]
  #=> "Alex"
h["group"] = h2[v]
  #=> h2["Alex"] => "B23" 
h #=> {"name"=>"Alex", "age"=>"4", "width"=>"55", "weight"=>"30",
  #    "species"=>"Alex", "female"=>"yes", "group"=>"B23"} 
h.to_a
  #=> [["name", "Alex"], ["age", "4"], ["width", "55"], ["weight", "30"],
  #    ["species", "Alex"], ["female", "yes"], ["group", "B23"]]
```

The calculation is similar for the second element of `arr1`.